# Regex substitute in a pre-found pattern (A two step process)

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to replace all the `\` in an `#include <...>` directives with `/`. And I would like to do it in one shot. Unfortunately I only found this which takes several lines:

```
if(/^\s*#include\s*(?:"|<)\K.*\\.*(?="|>)/) {
   my $r = $& =~ s|\\|/|gr;
   s/\Q$&\E/$r/g;
}
```

Or maybe better:

```
if(/^(\s*#include\s*(?:"|<))(.*\\.*)((?:"|>).*)$/) {
   my $r = $2 =~ s|\\|/|gr;
   s/\Q$1$2$3\E/$1$r$3/g;
}
```

For example, I could have this kind of input:

```
    #include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
```

And obtain:

```
    #include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
```

Can I make it better, prettier and shorter?

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `tr|\\|/| if /#include/`?

Comment: @Borodin Yes it will change the \comment\ in the comment with `/comment/` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be possible  through [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). The anchor `\G`matches at the position where the previous match ended. During the first match attempt, `\G` matches at the start of the string in the way `\A` does.

```
$ echo '    #include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/' | perl -pe 's~(?:^\s*#include\s*"|\G)[^\\"]*\K\\~/~g'
    #include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
$ echo '    #include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/' | perl -pe 's~(?:^\s*#include\s*"|\G)[^\\"]*\K\\(?=[^"]*")~/~g'
    #include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/1)

For both, the one-liner would be like,

```
$ echo '#include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/ "foo\bar"
  #include <...\...\foo\bar.c> foo\\bar' | perl -pe 's~(?:(?:^\s*#include\s*"|\G)[^\\">]*\K\\)|(?:(?:^\s*#include\s*<|\G)[^\\><]*\K\\(?=[^<>]*>))~/~g'
#include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/ "foo\bar"
  #include <.../.../foo/bar.c> foo\\bar
```

Comment: And the case where the delimiters are `<` and `>`?

Comment: Okay, but that should be your answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj maybe better to put it in a new regex101 session because if I click on your DEMO link I'm temped go to the latest version due to the "OLD VERSION" warning.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -i pe 's{^\s*\#include\s*[<"]+\K ([^">]+) (?=[">]+)}{ $1 =~ y|\\|/|r }xe' file
```

output

```
#include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[<"]+` and `[">]+` be just `[<"]` and `[">]`?

Comment: I think I prefer `s{ ^ \s* \#include \s* \K ( "[^"]+" | <[^>]+> ) }{ $1 =~ tr|\\|/|r }xe`, but this is probably the best of the answers. Well done.

Comment: @Borodin What don't you like with the `\G` and `\K` from Avinash answer?

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure if `<"foo/path/">` is also valid input.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `@-` and `@+` arrays with `substr` to apply the translation to only the required part. (See `@LAST_MATCH_START` and `@LAST_MATCH_END` in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).)

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = '#include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/';

say $s;

if ( $s =~ / \#include \s* ( "[^"]+" | <[^>]+> ) /x ) {
  substr($s, $-[1], $+[1]-$-[1]) =~ tr|\\|/|;
}

say $s;
```

**output**

```
#include "...\...\foo\bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
#include ".../.../foo/bar.c" /* Here */// a \comment\ /\/
```